# Turn indicator and high beam always on

Tags: electrical, citroen, citroen-c3

Citroen c3 1.4 03 ... I bought the car over a week ago. When I start the car up the right indicator comes on and also the high beam. I have to disconnect my battery to get them off but when I reconnect battery they come back on again

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'd take it back if you can, hopefully there's some sort of warranty! Does moving the indicator stalk change anything? For instance does pulling it back or pushing it forward do anything to the high beams?